# Drupal MP4 iPad streaming not working

Tags: ipad, drupal, mod-rewrite, video, mp4

I am trying to serve mp4s from a drupal-based site, but Safari iPad seems unable to play any mp4 located within the scope of the Drupal site (i.e. shows the play button crossed out) when I try to hit the file directly in the browser. I have done extensive header comparison serving the same file from a non-Drupal site (i.e. from a location that Safari iPad can play) and have not found this to be a header issue. I'm wondering if the PHP file piping and mod_rewrite'ing that are going on via Drupal are causing the problem, but if the headers match up and its the same file, what else could it be? I hope this is clear and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I have run into the same problem while serving video using Drupal's private file system (http://drupal.org/node/1289818). Is it possible for you to post your file_download hook solution here or perhaps expand on it a bit more?